# html form action and onclick

Tags: php, html, onclick, buttonclick

Here is a php file named upload_file.php :

```
<?php
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
?>
```

When I call the above file with the html form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Everything works great and I manage to upload the selected file in the /upload local server folder.

My question: What is the equivalent of the above form if I want to use onclick? I.e. in the following code

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="browse_file"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Browse for your file</h2>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="button" value="file" onclick= "location.href = 'upload_file.php'">
        </div>
```

that defines a popup window (that is controled by anothel modal dialog - thats why I do not want to use the form), what should be completed in order to pass the filename chosen to $_FILES when calling upload_file.php with onclick?

Thank you friends.

Comment: your question is not clear, you want the same form but you want the form to be submitted automaticaly when you choose a file ?

Comment: In the last chunk of code I provided what should we add to make it behave like the previous form? How can we pass the file the user chooses to $_FILES with onclick?

Comment: this is definetly not the right way to do this. You can't pass a file (wich is a post request) using a location.href, you have to use an ajax post request and if you really want a redirect you can fire it at the end of the upload

Comment: You cant use input! without form, My best suggestion is to use ajax onto achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about AJAX and javascript if you want to use onclick function with forms. There is very simple implementation of the ajax request in the jquery. Also you can easily get chosen file from the input by using jquery.

Comment: I am restricted by the implementation to use the code I posted to pass to $_FILES. Can I use in this code jquery? Say, maybe upon click, executing a jquery (somewhere placed in my html that calls the php)?

Comment: Why can't you use form? You cant use submit input, form tag or what ? Where is problem in your form? I dont think you can send files without form when you can't also use javascript.

Comment: If you tell us something more about "form" in your modal maybe you dont have to use ajax.